# How to Combine WIX Setup Project with WIX Bootstrapper Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wix, wix3.7

I have a WIX Setup Project that includes my custom UI and a WIX Bootstrapper Project that includes prerequsites/dependencies in form of exe and Msi of my projects.
I want to combine them to make a single exe.
If i give reference of my WIX Setup project in Bootstrapper Project then it did not display my WIX UI. However it is able to successfully installed my setup msi and prerequisites.

```
<Bundle Name="Bootstrapper1" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Microsoft" UpgradeCode="4056d930-16b2-44eb-a861-16db566ae44c">
  <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

  <Chain>
    <PackageGroupRef Id="Y"/>
    <MsiPackage SourceFile ="$(var.BiodentifySetUp.TargetPath)" Compressed ="yes" />
  </Chain>
</Bundle>
<Fragment>
  <PackageGroup Id="Y">
    <ExePackage Id="Y" DisplayName="software already install"
                       DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/2/562A10F9-C9F4-4313-A044-9C94E0A8FAC8/dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe" 
                       Compressed="no" Cache="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" 
                       Vital="yes" SourceFile=".\y.msi" InstallCommand="/passive /norestart" />
  </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

How can I merge them to make an exe?

Comment: Are you asking about putting all files into the bootstrapper exe or about showing the MSI UI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what i beleive you want to do is to use single exe to install all dependencies and your own msi and show your own MSI UI when it comes time to install your .msi packageand if I am not wrong with then you simply need to add **DisplayInternalUI='yes'** to the **MsiPackage** elements you want to display.

For example:

```
<Chain>
   ...
   <MsiPackage ... DisplayInternalUI='yes' />
</Chain>
```

and if it is like you want NO bootstrapper UI but only your MSI UI then there is no such bootstrapper application who will silently install your dependencies and will show your MSI UI.
Please clearly explain your requirement for better responses.